# Is a maximum likelihood estimator in an exponential family always sufficient?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family

An exponential family (under natural parameterization) is such that $p(X|\eta)=h(X)\exp\{\eta^\top T(X)-A(\eta)\}$, where $X$ is the data, $\eta$ is the natural parameter, and $h,T,A$ are some functions (that are interrelated).

The statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient, and the maximum likelihood estimator is $\hat\eta(X)$ is such that $\nabla A(\hat\eta(X))=T(X)$.

It therefore seems to me that the density can be written as $p(X|\eta)=h(X)\exp\{\eta^\top\nabla A(\hat\eta(X))-A(\eta)\}=h(X)\cdot f(\hat\eta(X),\eta)$, which entails that $\hat\eta(X)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Am I mistaken or is it sound to conclude that a maximum likelihood estimator in an exponential family is always sufficient?

Comment: Thank you. Which part of the "proof" fails if the parameterization is not minimal?

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to point me to a textbook or journal reference?

Comment: I deem your proof is enough: Provided$$\nabla A(\hat\eta(t))=t\tag{1}$$has one and only one solution$$\hat\eta(t)$$for almost every realisation $t$ of $T(X)$, the factorisation theorem applies. Cases where this condition fails may be for discrete exponential families, on the boundary of the support of  $T(X)$ and curved exponential families when the constraints on $\eta$ may be incompatible with (1). (But it is debatable this is a "natural" exponential family.)

Comment: Michael Jordan mentions the sufficiency of the mean parameter MLE [in his notes.](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter8.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can also turn it around. If the MLE is a (one-to-one) function of the sufficient statistic $\sum T(X_i)$, then it is itself a sufficient statistic as well.